# How to add new column to streaming data frame in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have data coming as a stream from kafka topic . In my dataframe I have "Average" column and I want to create new column by performing some calculation on "Average" column.

Currently I have written something like -

```
rdd_get_chills = df_avg_tmp.rdd.map(lambda line:get_wind_chills(line))
```

But it's throwing error -

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine `withColumn()` and custom `UDF` to add a new column over a streaming DF. The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to perform batch like operations on a streaming dataframe. If you wish to perform batch operations - you can try using `forEachBatch()` functionality of structured streaming - https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/foreach.html

You can try something like below to add a column on streaming Dataframe

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
incomingStreamDF.withColumn("newlyCalculatedColumnName", UDF_Function_To_Perform_Calculation(col(average))
```